# Maven Dependencies : non existing library 'hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar'

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am trying to implement an Spark app WordCount, but i get an error when I add hadoop-common dependency:

```
'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0-cdh5.9.0/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar'
```

and this my pom.xml :

```
  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

my haddop version is *2.6.0-cdh5.9.0*.
Any help please!!

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or use external jar and add http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0-cdh5.9.0/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar

hope this helps

Comment: Yes I tried the external jar and it work fine, but why it doesn't work automatically with maven. When I see in `/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/` I can't find **hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar**.

Comment: hadoop version 2.6.0-cdh5.9.0 is not valid in the central repo. check this http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.hadoop%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hadoop-common%22

Comment: Thanks, but i have an error when I run my program : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration`

Comment: how are you running the job?

Comment: I'm using scala so i run it with scala application

Comment: try building fat jar